# Python: creating a function from dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

How to create a function which calculates the total value from 2 given dictionary

Comment: Is this homework?  It is suspiciously precisely defined.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your data in a something like this:

```
Part = collections.namedtuple('Part', 'key name price')
parts = {
    'WH239': Part('WH239', 'Mountain Bike Wheel', 5000),
    'TR202': Part('TR202', 'Mountain Bike Tire', 2000),
    'TU277': Part('TU277', 'Mountain Bike Tube', 2000),
    'FR201': Part('FR201', 'Mountain Bike Frame', 60000), 
}

Product = collections.namedtuple('Product', 'key name parts')
product = Product(
    'bike201', 
    'Mountain Bike', 
    [('WH239', 2), ('TR202', 2), ('TU277', 2), ('FR201', 1)]
)
```

then you can do something like this:

```
product_price = sum(n*parts[part_name].price for part_name, n in product.parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d1 = dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> d2 = dict(a=2, b=1, c=3)
>>> c = Counter(**d1)
>>> c.update(**d2)
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 3})
```